# html/css table gets mangled in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, html-table

This is the website I'm working on and every other browser displays the table properly, but like always, when it comes to IE (specifically 9) it breaks.

http://lumpiahouserestaurant.com/menu/

I already fixed the `<thead>` problems because IE didnt interpret display:inline-block well. I cant find a similar problem with the `<tbody>`.

The main goal of the table is to have the `<tr>` floated left and the `<td>` to have display block so they display downwards.

Comment: Floating table cells? Doesn't that defeat the purpose of using tables in the first place?

Comment: It is tabular data, isn't that what tables are for? but html tables always read from left to right. This table data needed to be read from top to bottom. So to keep the data in the right rows and not mixed up I thought of this solution. It works in every other browser, why not IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tables are not designed to be written in this vertical way. While it could be a fun experiment to toy with browsers in this way, it sounds like a recipe for a headache in a production site.

If you insist on coding up your table this way (I'm guessing you want to do this because it's more intuitive to read in the HTML), you can either

1. Make an outer table with 7 columns and 1 row - one for each day. In each column create a table with `n` rows and 1 column to hold the data for each day. This is assuming that the table rows aren't supposed to be aligned, as in your example.
2. Do up your table from left to right rather than from top to bottom, then [use javascript to transpose the table.](http://assaneonline.blogspot.com/2011/02/looking-for-simpler-way-to-transpose.html)

Comment: Since you have a fixed width layout it might be easier to use floated <div>s instead of a table.  You can still write it intuitively, use floats, and it should render cleanly in all browsers.

Comment: @Jim Thomas I'd argue that as he's dealing with tabular data, a table is perfectly appropriate in this scenario. Always good to keep in mind that while tables are a hack for layouts, floating divs are also a hack, and require a multitude of clear fixes to get right cross-browser.

Comment: That's true, depending on the usage you often need to add a clear div after floated content.  However, I find that's often cleaner solution for the non-aligned layout he needs.  It will use less code than nested tables or javascript-heavy solutions. Ultimately either method will work, so I'd recommend using whatever is most comfortable and understandable to you.

Comment: I have actually tried it with divs already and felt that it created more problems trying to align everything and whatnot. Thanks for the answer @waitinforatrain, Im just waiting for other peoples answers before i choose yours which i think i should do anyways :]

Comment: I will give the divs a thought, but since the data in the table is coming from php sources and it IS tabular i might end up using nested tables.

Comment: Thanks @waitinforatrain everything is working now! it actually was easier to do option number 1 then the original method. I paired it with some IE specific css so that it displays properly and everything looks good in all modern browsers :]